# FromWasmAbi is not implemented for fn(SomeStruct) , while SomeStruct is #[wasm_bindgen]

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I have a 3 structs and two types defined

```
type OnMoveEvent = fn(Board) -> ();
type OnGameOverEvent = fn(Player) -> ();

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Game {
    on_move: OnMoveEvent,
    on_game_over: OnGameOverEvent,
    board: Board,
}
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Board {/* ... */}
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Player {/* ... */}
```

All 3 structs are `wasm_bindgen` and types can not be marked as `wasm_bindgen`. However types are just functions accepting structs and returning `void`

When I add `wasm_bindgen` to `Game` `impl` I get the following error

```
 --> src/game.rs:16:1
     |
  16 | #[wasm_bindgen]
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `wasm_bindgen::convert::traits::FromWasmAbi` is not implemented for `fn(board::Board)`
```

That is because `new` has the following signature

```
pub fn new(on_move: OnMoveEvent, on_game_over: OnGameOverEvent) -> Game
```

It seemed to me that it should be simple to translate types as they are functions accepting `wasm_bindgen` structs, but it appears as it's not the case

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

The full code [is here](https://github.com/venil7/rust-minimax/blob/master/src/game.rs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going to answer my own question after a bit of research:

Because I was trying to pass some functions from JS to Rust, those can not be guaranteed to have certain signature.

Instead `js-sys` crate provides a way to [Receiving JavaScript Closures in Exported Rust Functions](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/receiving-js-closures-in-rust.html#receiving-javascript-closures-in-exported-rust-functions)

I changed my code to following:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Game {
  board: Board,
  on_cpu_move: js_sys::Function,
  on_game_over: js_sys::Function,
}
```

and `new` signature looks like this:

```
  pub fn new(on_move: js_sys::Function, on_game_over: js_sys::Function) -> Game {
```

Then I need to call a callback that a `JS` consumer is going to provide, this is done like so:

```
...
let state = self.board.state();
let this = JsValue::NULL;

if state.game_over {
   let _ = self.on_game_over.call0(&this);
} else {
   let board = JsValue::from(self.board);
   let _ = self.on_cpu_move.call1(&this, &board);
}
...
```

It is up to `JS` consumer to make sure they provide right types.

hope somebody finds it useful.